# How i cannot remove top bar Android

Tags: android, xml, menu, fragment, titlebar

//MainAvtivity.java

```
mBottomBar = BottomBar.attach(this,savedInstanceState);
    mBottomBar.setItemsFromMenu(R.menu.menu_main, new OnMenuTabClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMenuTabSelected(@IdRes int i) {

            if(i == R.id.Bottombaritemone)
            {
                basketsFragment f = new basketsFragment();
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame,f).commit();
            }
            if(i == R.id.Bottombaritemtwo)
            {
                trackingFragment f = new trackingFragment();
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame,f).commit();
            }

            if(i == R.id.Bottombaritemfour)
            {
                homeFragment f = new homeFragment();
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame,f).commit();
            }
            if(i == R.id.Bottombaritemfive)
            {
                setting f = new setting();
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame,f).commit();
            }
        }
```

//Main_activity.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

//Sample of HomeFragment

```
public class homeFragment extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home,container,false);
    return v;

}
```

//HomeFragment.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#FF7F50">
<TextView
    android:background="#FF7F50"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Restaurant"

    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

//menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:Theme="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen">
<item android:id="@+id/Bottombaritemfour"
    android:title="Restaurant"
    android:icon="@drawable/home"

    ></item>

<item android:id="@+id/Bottombaritemone"
    android:title="baskets"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:icon="@drawable/cart">
</item>

<item android:id="@+id/Bottombaritemtwo"
    android:icon="@drawable/car"
    android:title="tracking"
    ></item>


<item android:id="@+id/Bottombaritemfive"
    android:title="setting"
    android:icon="@drawable/setting"
    ></item>
```

I want the output to be like this:

### [image]

But it displays this to me (The title i want not at most top):

### [image]

// I already put at style.xml

```
`<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
</style>`
```

Comment: Did you put this style to MainAvtivity.java in your manifest?

Comment: Yes i have. android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen"

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is a BottomBar library bug. Try this. https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar/issues/197

Comment: Where should i put ?
if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
getSupportActionBar().hide();
}

Comment: Add it in onCreate() method. But first, delete from style     
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

Comment: What BottomBar are you using? And what version?

Comment: I just tried this https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar, version 2.1.1. And everything works well.  You probably are using older version. Try to upgrade to a new version.